# Remove MKAnnotation from MapView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, mkmapview, mkannotation

Ok, I can add pin on my map by LongPress on any place of map. Now I need to delete pins. So I want next: when I click on my pin, appear the name of pin and a little button with cross ((X) like in all apps to close), when user will click this button (X) - pin must be deleted. Can I do this? Or maybe there is another simple way to delete pin for user without go to detailview about this pin?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. For remove all annotation use this code.

   [yourMapView removeAnnotation:yourMapView.annotations];
2. For remove one annotation just implement logic For example...

   First remove all annotation and also remove your selected pin data from the array and after add this new array and add annotation..

Comment: Thanks, I know this method, but I need a little button for deleting, and I don't understand how can I create X button in callout of my pin

Comment: @Neznajka see my updated answer  dude.. here this is a way which i implement in my one project dude...

Comment: Yeah, thanks, I thought about it. But I thought that is not good method =) Ok, if not only me see such solution  - it's good =)

Comment: always wel-come dude... :)

Answer (score 2):

```
// REMOVING ALL ANNOTATION
    for (id <MKAnnotation>  myAnnot in [objMapView annotations])
    {
        if (![myAnnot isKindOfClass:[MKUserLocation class]])
        {
            [objMapView removeAnnotation:myAnnot];
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please edit your answer to add an explanation of how your code works and how it solves the OP's problem. Many SO posters are newbies and will not understand the code you have posted.